# Best practice for creating a list of userIDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql, razor

I have a database structured as follows :

```
UserID (Primary Key)
Username
FirstName
SecondName
Email
```

I plan to allow users to query this database and add other users so that an algorithm can be ran to pick the free times of all those users and return the times available for meetings.

So, firstly, I need to build up a list of users. What is the best practice for doing this? I am assuming I will create a cookie each time a user is found and add it to the clients session? How can I do this?

My code so far is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#username').autocomplete({source:'getProducts'});
        });
</script>
@{      
         if (IsPost) {
                var db = Database.Open("mPlan");
                var term = Request.Form["username"];
                var sql = "SELECT * from Users where Username = @0 OR FirstName = @0 OR SecondName = @0"; //this is not very good
                var result = db.Query(sql, term);


                HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("MPUsersToMeet");
                if(cookie == null) {
                   //assuming I need to create a new cookie
                        cookie = new HttpCookie("MPUsersToMeet");
                } else {
                    //cookie.Add();?
                }
        }
 }
            <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
            <h1>Organize your meeting!</h1>
            <p>Please give us the details of your meeting.</p>
            <label>Who do you want to add to your meeting?
            <span class="small">Add your first name, separate by commas.</span>
            </label>
             <label for="username">Enter name : </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

            <button type="submit">Add</button>
            <div class="spacer"></div>            
            </form>
```

What would be the best practice here? I need to query the database and store on the clientside a list of users, and then render these users details on the screen.

Comment: first off, I'd remove this code from the UI and place it in the appropriate layer

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe , I have done this; my code is just showing snippets so that things don't get obfuscated with simple markup! :)

Comment: why do you think you need cookies? Usually the cookies are used to keep track of the logged user, not to represent a list of users.

Comment: @themarcuz, thank you for the response. It was just an idea, I am confused with how the client would be keep track of the list of users added so far, cookies were the only way I could think to do it!

Comment: Are you looking to gather a list of concurrent users, or a master list of all users who have accessed your application?

Comment: @Jeff I am looking to allow users to type another users name into a textbox, validate that the name exists in my database, and then press add and have the users name and ID saved and displayed on screen so that it can be used in my algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must decide if the list of user ids should be built server side or client side.

If its built server side, then each user id must be posted to the server. For this solution, the page must be reloaded for every added user. I would have solved this by using a html form tag with a list of hidden user ids.

If you take the client side approach and implement this with javascript a list of user ids can be built and when all users are added, it can be posted to the server. In Javascript you can use arrays to store multiple users, so there is no need for using cookies. When all users are selected, the array can either be sent to the server by an AJAX request or with a normal POST.

Comment: How can I do this on the client side ? I would like to maintain a list of all users, and each time the client presses "Add", their details to be added to a list which is stored on the client side. I am very unsure how I would go about this.

Comment: Add an onclick handler on your html add button. Keep a list of user ids, when the click handler fires add the new user id to the list. Google "javascript onclick".

Comment: Thank you. And if I was to try and do it on the server side, how would I go about this? I realise I would need to query the database each time the user entered something into the textbox, however, how would I save the contents of their list so far?

Comment: For each added user the page needs to be reloaded and rendered. The entered user name should be posted to the server and the database queried, if its correct it should be added as a hidden field to the form tag. But you must also make sure that all previous added users are kept in the forms tag.